# AppCenter Test and Distribution version not being picked up from info.plist

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I am using AppCenter to build, test and "trying to" distribute my app to the iPhone App Store. I am using AppCenter environment variables to set the version via the CFBundleShortVersionString string in a pre build bash script similar to what James Montemagno does here with his Version Bumping.

https://montemagno.com/vs-app-center-custom-build-scripts-for-production-apps/

When I look at the info.plist file in the log everything looks fine i.e. version = 2.0.1 and build number is correct. But the when I look at the tests or the release history the version is still 1.0 (see image). This then causes me problems when trying to distribute to that App Store.

Has anyone had something similar and how did they solve it?

[image]

Comment: Try to message montemagno on twitter, he should respond!